# Unable to set session variable in firefox and safari browser

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, session-variables

I am setting the session variable using Ajax, its working fine in chrome but not working in safari and Firefox browser

This is my Ajax method:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_wdm_add_user_custom_data_options', 'wdm_add_user_custom_data_options_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_wdm_add_user_custom_data_options', 'wdm_add_user_custom_data_options_callback');
function wdm_add_user_custom_data_options_callback()
{
    //Custom data - Sent Via AJAX post method
    $product_id = $_POST['custom_data_4']; 
    $custom_data_1 = $_POST['custom_data_1']; 
    $custom_data_2 = $_POST['custom_data_2'];
    $custom_data_3 = $_POST['custom_data_3'];


    $_SESSION['product_idd'] = $product_id;
    $_SESSION['custom_data_1'] = $custom_data_1;
    $_SESSION['product_pos'] = $custom_data_2;
    $_SESSION['product_lmm'] = $custom_data_3;
       die();
}
```

When I am trying to print the $_SESSION and $_POST value inside above Ajax method its working fine for all browser but when I try to assign above session variable in below function:-

```
function kia_add_cart_item_data( $cart_item, $product_id ){

   if(isset($_SESSION['product_pos']) && $_SESSION['product_idd']==$cart_item['product_id']){
            $posnumber=$_SESSION['product_pos'];
        }else{
            $posnumber=1;
        }
        if(isset($_SESSION['product_lmm']) && $_SESSION['product_idd']==$cart_item['product_id']){
            $lmmnumber=$_SESSION['product_lmm'];
        }else{
            $lmmnumber=1;
        }

        $array['product_id'] = $product_id;


        $cart_item['product_pos'] = $posnumber;
        $cart_item['product_lmm'] = $lmmnumber;
    return $cart_item;

}
```

Then I am getting else part value in case of Firefox and safari browser while it's working fine in chrome.

Please help me why I am not getting the session value in Firefox and safari.

Comment: where is session_start .

Comment: I defined it at top of function.php                                                               
function form_startSession()
{
    if (!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
}
add_action('init', 'form_startSession', 1);

Comment: try inside the function and print_r the $_SESSION also

Comment: where i have to define?

Comment: add session_start(); in both functions

Comment: added but result is still same in Firefox and safari.

Comment: Which hosting provider are you using? I know some hosts cache prevents the use of the native `$_SESSION` global. Like Pantheon. Have you tried installing the Native PHP Sessions Plugin? https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-native-php-sessions/

Comment: Yes, but problems is still persists.

Comment: When I checked via phpinfo() then I found session.save_path has no value on the server. Is there a problem due to this?

Answer (score 0):

According to me you need to use wordpress session over here.

```
$wp_session = WP_Session::get_instance();
```

For example :

```
$wp_session = WP_Session::get_instance();
$wp_session ['product_idd'] = $product_id;
```

Above is for store the value in session and below if for how you can get the value

```
$wp_session = WP_Session::get_instance();
echo $wp_session ['product_idd'];
```

Try with this method and let me know if it is working or not for you

Comment: When I checked via phpinfo() then I found session.save_path has no value on the server. Is there a problem due to this?

Comment: You can do that by this : ini_set('session.save_path', '/path/to/your/folder')

Comment: Do I have to define it in php.ini file?

Comment: if you are having the access of ini file than you need to do over there if not than you can do this code in index.php or config.php

Comment: Did you change in the php.ini file?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was forget to pass async : false inside jQuery.ajax. Now Its working fine.

what does Async:false do in ajax

"async:false will hold the execution of rest code. Once you get response of ajax, only then, rest of the code will execute"

Comment: It can hang your browser.