# $_SESSION does not save status

Tags: php, html, wordpress, plugins

I'm developing a plugin for Wordpress and my problem is when I try to save some arrays, messages or button status doesn't save this. I need help!!

```
    if($strA2==$strB2) {
         echo "<li>"."Esto le puede interesar! " . $v1;
         $interest_post[]=$v1;
         $_SESSION['array_interes'] = $interest_post;

         //Boton Eliminar
         echo '<form action="" method="post">';
         echo '<input type="submit" value="Eliminar" name='. $cont_remove_button .' />';
         echo '</form>';

         if(isset($_POST[$cont_remove_button])){
            unset($interest_post[$cont]);
            $_SESSION['mensaje_eliminado'] = "Elemento eliminado";

            echo $_SESSION['mensaje_eliminado'];
            $suggest[]=$v1;
            $_SESSION['array_sugerencia'] = $suggest;

          }
          $cont_remove_button=$cont_remove_button+1;
          $cont=$cont+1;
          }else{
            $suggest[]=$v1;
            $_SESSION['array_sugerencia'] = $suggest;
          }
        }
}
```

I try to clarify more when I press a button and then another, the action of the first button is not saved. I don't know if I used $_SESSION correctly or there is other way to do this.

Comment: Do you have `session_start()` anywhere before a `$_SESSION` call is made?

Comment: @IsThisJavascript Yes, I have session_start()...

Comment: Donot use  core php session syntax use wordpress session syntax. Did you try with it?

Comment: @AkshayShah I tried with:                                                
add_action('init', 'cyb_session_start', 1);
function cyb_session_start() {
    if( ! session_id() ) {
        session_start();
    }
}

Comment: @AkshayShah But dosent work

Comment: This is not wordpress session

Comment: Check my answer over : here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50583322/unable-to-set-session-variable-in-firefox-and-safari-browser/50583984#comment88212264_50583984

Answer (score 0):

You must check status before start :

Recommended way for versions of PHP >= 5.4.0 , PHP 7

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
```

Reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php

For versions of PHP < 5.4.0

```
if(session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
}
```